# Is it possible to refactor executing tests with include_partial?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

For example I have:

```
public function executeTestOne(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->value = Doctrine::getTable('Test')->createQuery('a')->where('id = ?', $request->getParameter('id') ) ->execute(); 
}

public function executeTestTwo(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  $this->value = Doctrine::getTable('Test')->createQuery('a')->where('id = ?', $request->getParameter('id') ) ->execute(); 
}
```

I would like to use `include_partial` or `render_partial` etc in action:

```
public function executePartial ???? 
{
  $this->value = Doctrine::getTable('Test')->createQuery('a')->where('id = ?', $request->getParameter('id') ) ->execute(); 
}


public function executeTestOne(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  include_partial($this->value ??);
}

public function executeTestTwo(sfWebRequest $request)
{
  include_partial($this->value ??);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really get what you're trying to do, but what about this?

```
public function executeTestQuery($id) {
    $this->value = Doctrine::getTable('Test')->createQuery('a')->where('id = ?', $id ) ->execute(); 
}


public function executeTestOne(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   executeTestQuery($request->getParameter('id'));
} 

public function executeTestTwo(sfWebRequest $request)
{
   executeTestQuery($request->getParameter('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically yes if you load the `PartialHelper`. But if you're doing this then you're doing something **very** wrong in your application, so please never under any circumstances do this... ever.

If you really can't think of a better way to do this, then what you really need is a `component` not a partial. [See here.](http://www.symfony-project.org/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/07-Inside-the-View-Layer#chapter_07_sub_components)